# understanding the protocol family argument of socket() and result list of getaddrinfo()

Tags: c, sockets, protocols, getaddrinfo

I had started Network Programming some days ago but there is some confusion that I need to clear. I have not studied much networking or tcp/ip protocol before.

**Socket function argument:**

The *protocol family* argument to *socket* function denote the set of protocols or *protocol suite* that will be used for communication.

1. Is the above interpretation correct?

   If yes, then that means PF/AF_INET and PF/AF_INET6 are two different protocol suites. Right? So what is the reason for creating two different protocol suites and not one tcp/ip protocol suite with two address families?

   If not, then what does *protocol family* denote as the function argument?

   *EDIT*: Don't have Enough reputation to answer my own question so Editing

   **From Unix Network Programming Vol. 1, 3rd edition - Section 4.2 *socket* Function, Sub-section - AF_XXX Verseus PF_XXX**

   > The "`AF_`" prefix stands for "address family" and the "`PF_`" prefix stands for "protocol family". Historically, the intent was that a single protocol family might support multiple address families and that the `PF_` value was used to create the socket and the `AF_` value was used in socket addresses structures. But in actually, a protocol family supporting multiple address families has never been supported and the `sys/socket.h` header defines the `PF_` value for a given protocol to be equal to the `AF_` value for that protocol. While there is no guarantee that this equality between the two will always be true, should anyone change this for existing protocols, lots of existing code would break.

   So I guess that the reason for not creating one `PF_INET` protocol family with two address families `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` was *backward compatibility*.

***getaddrinfo*:**

The following code prints information about each ip address returned by *getaddrinfo*.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 201112l

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void print_family(struct addrinfo *aip)
{
    printf(" family ");
    switch (aip->ai_family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
            printf("inet");
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            printf("inet6");
            break;
    }
}
void print_type(struct addrinfo *aip)
{
    printf(" type ");
    switch (aip->ai_socktype)
    {
        case SOCK_STREAM:
            printf("stream");
            break;
        case SOCK_DGRAM:
            printf("datagram");
            break;
        case SOCK_SEQPACKET:
            printf("seqpacket");
            break;
        case SOCK_RAW:
            printf("raw");
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown %d", aip->ai_socktype);
    }
}
void print_protocol(struct addrinfo *aip)
{
    printf(" protocol ");
    switch (aip->ai_protocol)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("0");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_TCP:
            printf("TCP");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_UDP:
            printf("UDP");
            break;
        case IPPROTO_RAW:
            printf("raw");
        case IPPROTO_SCTP:
            printf("sctp");
            break;
        default:
            printf("unknown %d", aip->ai_protocol);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct addrinfo *ailist, *aip, hint;
    int err;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <hostname> <service>\n", argv[0]);
        printf("If any one is not applicable, then provide NULL in its place.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "NULL") == 0)
        argv[1] = NULL;
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "NULL") == 0)
        argv[2] = NULL;
    hint.ai_flags = 0;
    hint.ai_family = 0;
    hint.ai_socktype = 0;
    hint.ai_protocol = 0;
    hint.ai_addrlen = 0;
    hint.ai_canonname = NULL;
    hint.ai_addr = NULL;
    hint.ai_next = NULL;
    if ((err = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hint, &ailist)) != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo error: %s", gai_strerror(err));
        return 2;
    }

    for (aip = ailist; aip != NULL; aip = aip->ai_next)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in *sinp;
        struct sockaddr_in6 *sinp6;
        char buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        const char *addr;

        print_family(aip);
        print_type(aip);
        print_protocol(aip);
        printf("\n\thost %s", aip->ai_canonname ? aip->ai_canonname : "-");
        if (aip->ai_family == AF_INET)
        {
            sinp = (struct sockaddr_in *) aip->ai_addr;
            addr = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sinp->sin_addr, buf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf(" address %s", addr ? addr : "unknown");
            printf(" port %d ", ntohs(sinp->sin_port));
        }
        else if (aip->ai_family == AF_INET6)
        {
            sinp6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) aip->ai_addr;
            addr = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &sinp6->sin6_addr, buf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf(" address %s", addr ? addr : "unknown");
            printf(" port %d ", ntohs(sinp6->sin6_port));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running above program on arch linux 4.4.11-1-lts x86-64.

Running the program as: `./prg localhost http` gives following result (for ipv4 addresses):-

```
family inet type stream protocol TCP
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 80 
family inet type datagram protocol UDP
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 80 
family inet type stream protocol sctp
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 80 
family inet type seqpacket protocol sctp
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 80
```

And for the command `./prg localhost NULL` result is:-

```
family inet type stream protocol TCP
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 0 
family inet type datagram protocol UDP
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 0 
family inet type raw protocol 0
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 0
```

2. My question is how does it return result when service is NULL? The man page says that the port will be left uninitialized but there is nothing about the number of structures returned. why does it give *addrinfo* structure for *tcp* and *udp* when service is NULL and not for *sctp*? Is *sctp* not in its default list of protocols to return structures for when service is NULL, if there is such default?

**From Unix Network Programming Vol. 1 3rd edition By W. Richard Stevens**

> It would be acceptable for `getaddrinfo` to return an `ai_protocol` of 0 for the two `SOCK_STREAM` structures if that is sufficient to specify TCP (it is not sufficient if the system implements SCTP, for example), and an `ai_protocol` of 0 for the two `SOCK_DGRAM` structures if the system doesn't implement any other `SOCK_DGRAM` protocols for IP.

3. As I understood above line, `getaddrinfo` can return 0 as protocol if there is only one protocol for the specified socket type. `This would be acceptable.` My system implements `sctp` and maybe other protocols for `SOCK_DGRAM` socket types so it cannot return 0 as protocol value for `TCP` and `UDP`? Then why does it return protocol value of 0 for `SOCK_RAW` socket type as there are many protocols supported by raw sockets under `AF_INET` family?

**The man page says**

> There are several reasons why the linked list may have more than one addrinfo structure, including: the network host is multihomed, accessible  over  multiple protocols  (e.g.,  both  AF_INET  and  AF_INET6);  or the same service is available from multiple socket types (one SOCK_STREAM address and another SOCK_DGRAM address, for example).

4. Is saying "service available from multiple socket types" same as saying that "service is supported by or available from multiple protocols"?

Changing the line of code `hint.ai_socktype=0` to `hint.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM` and running as `./prg localhost http` gives following result:

```
family inet type stream protocol TCP
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 80
```

5. Why did it not give one structure for `SCTP` which is supported by `SOCK_STREAM` socket type as the following result shows.

Changing the line in the modified program  `hint.ai_protocol=0` to`hint.ai_protocol=IPPROTO_SCTP` and running as `./prg localhost http` gives following result:

```
family inet type stream protocol sctp
        host - address 127.0.0.1 port 80
```

Comment: `PF/AF_INET` is for IPv4, `PF/AF_INET6` is for IPv6.  The are different transport protocols. TCP, UDP, these run on top of IP, they don't care if IPv4 or IPv6 is being used, the TCP/UDP data is the same either way. `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)` creates a socket that communicates using TCP over IPv4. `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)` for UDP over IPv4. `socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)` for TCP over IPv6. `socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)` for UDP over IPv6.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @RemyLebeaeu Sorry, I pressed Enter by mistake. But I was asking that since AF_INET is used as domain/protocol family this should mean that it represents a set of protocols which in this case should be TCP/IP protocol suite if the protocol family mean protocol suite (set of protocols). For example - for bluetooth we use different domain AF_BLUETOOTH which should represent a set of protocols and not just one protocol. The protocol to use is given in the protocol argument. So first argument cannot be just one protocol.

Comment: The socket design has separate address and protocol families for generality, but in practice they always go together: you use `PF_INET` with `AF_INET` and `PF_INET6` with `AF_INET6`. The possibility of using multiple address families within a protocol family is a general feature that I don't think has ever been exploited.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barmar. Reason for a protocol family not supporting multiple address families was backward compatibility. Edited my post with resource. But still I am assuming that the protocol family in the function argument denote the protocol suite (for example AF_INET denote TCP/IP protocol suite with ipv4 protocol and will use that protocol stack for communication) because I cannot think of a better explanation for this.